# Refresh position of element in React on location not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to change the left position of some objects every time a certain event occurs. How could I do that?

I am rendering a list of components in another component. Those elements are positioned `absolute` and the (random) `left` position gets passed as props.

```
getAllWorksTiles() {
  const elementsList = this.getElementsList();

  return elementsList.map(
    e =>
      <WorksTile
        title={ e.title }
        description={ e.description }
        key={ e.title }
        left={ this.getRandomHPos() }
        image={ e.image }
        link={ e.link }/>
  )
}

getRandomHPos() {
  return Math.random() * 60;
}
```

I am using React Router DOM and I would like to re-position those elements every time the page gets either PUSHED or PULLED (so `this.props.history.action !== 'REPLACE'`).

I have tried to re-mount the whole component but I am sure that there is a smarter way?

Comment: store `left` in state, and then use `setState` to update it.

Comment: keep your random position in state. and update state when getRandomPos is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the 'left' value in the state, and use that value to style your element.

Whenever your 'certain event' occurs, you call a function which performs the randomisation, and via setState() updates the 'left' state.

setState() will cause a rerender - which will in turn, update the location of you element

example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pj8rp70zo0